# Android-recycleView can't show out and i don't know hot to show the value to my TextView

Tags: android

I got two problems as title

First is my `recycleView` can't show out，i return view on the void `onCreateViewHolder` in MyAdapter Class and setAdapter in MainActivity Class，but it doesn't work

the second is it seems my List arrayList is null
i get the four values successfully from Json，because i can see the `Log:FinallyJson` information 
i try to put the four value in use two codes

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(name, address, tel, words);    
arrayList.add(transaction);
```

It doesn't work too. It makes me confused all day. How can i show out the `recycleView` and let the four values `setAdaper` successfully.

Can somebody can teach me the solution?

Here is my three Classes:

```java
public class *MyAdapter* extends RecyclerView.Adapter< MyAdapter.MyViewHolder >{
    private Context context;
    private List<Transaction> mDatas;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Transaction> datas) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDatas = datas;
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private  TextView name,address,tel,words;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_textView);
            address=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_textView);
            tel=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tel_textView);
            words=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.words_textView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=View.inflate(parent.getContext(),R.layout.cardview,null);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(mDatas.get(position).getName().toString());
        holder.address.setText(mDatas.get(position).getAddress().toString());
        holder.tel.setText(mDatas.get(position).getTel().toString());
        holder.words.setText(mDatas.get(position).getWords().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDatas.size();
    }
}

public class Transaction {
    String name;
    String address;
    String tel;
    String words;

    public Transaction() {
    }

    public Transaction(String name, String address, String tel, String words) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.words = words;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(String words) {
        this.words = words;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private final String url = "http://data.coa.gov.tw/Service/OpenData/EzgoTravelFoodStay.aspx";
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public List<Transaction> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyTask().execute(url);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,arrayList));

        Log.d("Array:",arrayList.toString());
    }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String url = strings[0];
            try {
                String routeJson = getRouteJson(url);
                return routeJson;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            showRoute(s);    
        }
    }
    private String getRouteJson(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        StringBuilder jsonIn = new StringBuilder();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonIn.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "responseCode:" + responseCode);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "jsonIn:" + jsonIn);
        return jsonIn.toString();
    }
    private void showRoute(String route) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(route);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("jsonObject", jsonObject.toString());
                String name = jsonObject.getString("Name").toString();
                String address = jsonObject.getString("Address").toString();
                String tel = jsonObject.getString("Tel").toString();
                String words = jsonObject.getString("HostWords").toString();
                Transaction transaction = new Transaction(name, address, tel, words);
                arrayList.add(transaction);
                Log.d("FinallyJson:", name + "," + address + "," + tel + "," + words);
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to help out: you might want to look into the Retrofit library. It will make getting json objects from the internet and turning them into objects really easy. In your case, you just tell Retrofit that you expect a Transaction object from the web service and it does all the conversion for you.

Comment: thanks i got the solution~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `youradapter.notifyDataChanged()` after populating the arraylist in `showRoute()` method.That's your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your solution , it is very simple and clear

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the reference to your adapter in a field:

    `public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private mAdapter adapter;`

and calling notifyDatasetChanged() after the for-loop:

   `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

Comment: Thanks for your help . It works ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Call this line after `showRoute(s)` in your `onPostExecute` function:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,arrayList));
```

Or either you have to make the adapter global and set arraylist to it. Then you can call `notifyDatasetChanged` to refresh the list.

Comment: Thank you for the information , i really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.